# UIFont Custom Style Setting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont, custom-font

I am having a font name: `HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman 55.otf`. 
I added it in my `info.plist` file.

When I write code :

```
UIFont *fontHalvetikaNeueLTStd = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Std" size:55];
```

It works Fyn!

But when I added following Code with Font style, it returns me `nil`.

```
UIFont *fontHalvetikaNeueLTStd = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Std 55 Roman" size:55];
```

How can I set "Roman 55" style in my Custom Font?

Solved By Adding Following:

Verify Font name By:

```
NSLog (@"Font families: %@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Std"]);
```

Output:

Font families: (

```
"HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt",
"HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman"
```

)

Then Set By:

```
UIFont *fontHalvetikaNeueLTStd = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman" size:size];
```

Thanks to all your hints.

Comment: First add font **Helvetica Neue LT Std 55 Roman** in your system and then try/.

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/#includefonts can help you a lot. It works for me :)

Comment: hi @iPatel I have already added it,

Comment: @ArtemZ. this link is not opened

Comment: @Myaaoonn http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/ try this, but there are 3 upvotes for my comment, I think it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time when we add custom fonts in our application need to review first about the font name and font full name. please review.

if yes then review font with the name `Helvetica Neue LT Std 55 Roman` exist in your system or not.

- Use font `file name` in `plist`, and `font name` in your `iOS`
  code.

If you want to know all the load fonts in your app review this code.

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])   {
    NSLog(@"Font Family = %@", family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])   {
        NSLog(@"Font Name = %@", name);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Swift code snippet

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames() {
    print("Font Family = \(family)")
    for name in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family) {
        print("Font Name = \(name)")
    }
}
```

Swift 4

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("Font Family = \(family)")
        for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
            print("Font Name = \(name)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the font file with name `Helvetica Neue LT Std 55 Roman` and add the entry to info plist. It will work fine.

Comment: @Parce I added it in info. Jst wnt 2 knw d r8 way in "FontFamily"